# Converting Postgresql Interval to day

Tags: java, intervals, date-conversion

I have an interval string from Postgres like

```
5 years 6 months 3 days
```

It comes directly from the database. Is there an easy way to convert it to days? I only did it with regex expression, but I'm wondering if theres something more efficient. I need it to be done using Java, as the query is hardcoded on the database as a procedure and I don't have permission to change it.

Comment: Please show us the code which generated this string.

Comment: It comes from a direct query from jooq, its a simple select

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure Postgres has a way to get a date diff directly in days.  Some sample data and the query would help here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your answer is not helpful for the OP but it is for me and for others, so why you delete it!

Comment: @YCF_L: because Adao wants Java code, not SQL (and the query can't be changed). That why I also removed the relevant tags.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree, but it still helpful to us no!, but it's up to you to keep it or not ;)

Comment: @YCF_L You could ask a separate question concerning conversion directly in SQL if you want to conserve the answer.

Comment: You cannot precisely convert the interval to number of days without a base date (as months have different numbers of days). You can get only an approximation.